# Curves contracted by a rational map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, birational-geometry, divisors, line-bundles

Let $D$ be a big but not nef divisor on a normal $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial projective variety. Assume that the section ring 
$$R(D) = \bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}}H^0(X,nD)$$
is finitely generated and consider the rational map
$$\phi_{D}:X\dashrightarrow X_{D}\subseteq Proj(R(D))$$
Could it happen that for any effective irreducible curve $C\subseteq X$ such that $C\cdot D=0$ (zero intersection product) we have that $C$ is contained in the indeterminacy locus of $\phi_{D}$ ?

Comment: It can happen yes, e.g., if $\phi_D$ is an embedding.

Comment: I was implicitly excluding that case, $D$ is not nef. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the Hirzebruch surface $\mathbb{F}_n$, $n>1$. Let $\sigma$ be the negative section and $\ell$ be the rulling. Consider $D=\ell+\sigma$, which is a big but not nef divisor. This $D$ satisfies your requirement, because there is no such curve $C$ such that $D\cdot C=0$.

Comment: $D$ is not big.

Comment: @abx sure it is. $(n+1)D\geq (n+1)\ell+\sigma$. The latter is ample.